# jQuery isotope with checkboxes and slider filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I created a page with jQuery isotope and various filters. Here's the simplified JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/itzuki87/21kfqhop/17/

As you can see, there are 3 filters: 2 checkboxes and 1 range sliders. All filters work well if used alone, but when I use them combined, it only works the last used filter.
This is because I use the ".show-me" class when I use the range slider, and the other classes when I use the checkboxes.

Range Slider:

```
$("#range").ionRangeSlider({
        hide_min_max: true,
        keyboard: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 150,
        from: 20,
        to: 110,
        type: 'double',
        step: 1,
        prefix: "&euro;",
        grid: true,
        onChange: function(data) {
            $(".grid-item").each(function(){
            price = parseInt($(this).find(".price").text(), 10);
            if (data.from <= price && data.to >= price) {
                $(this).addClass('show-me');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('show-me');
            }
            });
            $container.isotope({
             itemSelector: '.grid-item',
             filter: '.show-me'
         });
        }
});
```

Checkboxes:

```
$checkboxes.on('change', function(){
    filters = [];       
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
        filters.push(this.value);
    });     

    filters = filters.join('');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: filters
    });     

});
```

How can I do so that the two types of filters work in sync? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by myself. I simply added

```
$(".grid-item").addClass("show-me");
filters.push(".show-me");
```

at the beginning,

```
filters.push(".show-me");
```

in the checkboxes function, and I changed the slider function with

```
filter: filters
```

So every item has the "show-me" class at the beginning, that is removed with the range slider if the number is not corresponding.

The edited JSfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/21kfqhop/23/

Comment: I am sure I don’t have a full picture of what exactly this is for but in your example if you start just with the slider all the boxes disappears which in my view is wrong as user should be able to use any of the filters to narrow down the selection of boxes.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved adding `filters = filters.join('')` at the beggining. Now the JSFiddle should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You created your example based on the older version of the Isotope

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/combination-filters.html

There is a difference between versions and how filters can be combined:

V1: .red or .tall, you can pass in a filter selector of both: .red.tall

V2: .red or .tall, you can pass in a filter selector of both: .red, .tall

```
filters = filters.join(', ');
```

Please have a look at http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JGKyrY and I am sure you will be able to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: If I change `filters = filters.join(' ');` to `filters = filters.join(', ');` I get the checkboxes where the parameters are added. I want the checkboxes narrow parameters, and that's what I created.
My script: Big + Yellow returns only the big yellow box.
My script with the change you posted: Big + Yellow returns all the big boxes + all the yellow boxes, and this is not what I want.
My problem lies elsewhere, namely to operate the slider along with the checkboxes, allowing me to still further narrow the field.